# Radio buttons as options in Drop-down object

Tags: html

Is it possible to add radio buttons as options in a drop-down object?

Answer (score 1):

Not in a default `<select>` element. You'll have to build your own dropdown.

Comment: I hope so, or he won't be able to build his own.

Comment: we'll I'm not actually sure how to do my own dropdown without using <select>

Comment: @Jan-Dean Fajardo: why do you want this? whats the use case

Comment: @Jan-DeanFajardo you'll need divs, css, and probably some javascript. Or use something pre-built.

Comment: Well it's just simplifying the view. Well anyway, I think I got a solution. I use jQuery's widget for Multiselect. http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Comment: @bfavaretto: very true. i was gonna suggest bootstrap(#dropdowns) too. but OPs link is very good. I still dont get the use case. select and a radiobuttonlist both select one from a list. whats the point in having rblist in a dropdown?

Comment: I removed the link to bootstrap as I think the widget the OP found is likely to be what he's looking for. I guess it's probably for quick filtering.